# How can we automatically register callbacks for Events?

Tags: c#

I am developing a system that will have a wide variety of components; they are referred to as models. The primary structure that consumes these models is to be very generic; it is unaware of the details of each model. What we do know is that each model will potentially publish or subscribe to a range of topics. How can I store each modules published/subscribed topics with their corresponding callback, to be automatically registered with other models in the system?

I have attached my example attempt below. I think that I am close, but I am getting type conversion errors with my callback storing dictionaries. Ideally, each model should contain a directory for event callbacks and producers that I can register with generic logic in a parent system so that they all communicate.

```
namespace ctest
{
    class Program
    {
    class Model
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, EventHandler<EventArgs>> pub = new Dictionary<string, EventHandler<EventArgs>>();
        public Dictionary<string, Func<object, EventArgs>> sub = new Dictionary<string, Func<object, EventArgs>>();
    }

    class DataModel : Model
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DataRecieved;

        public DataModel()
        {
            pub.Add("data", DataRecieved);
        }

        public virtual void onData()
        {
            if (DataRecieved != null)
            {
                DataRecieved(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    class ReporterModel : Model
    {
        public ReporterModel()
        {
            sub["data"] = onData;
        }

        public void onData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("[reporter]" + " (data)");
        }
    }
        static void Main()
        {
            // Build Framework Models
            DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
            ReporterModel reporterModel = new ReporterModel();

            List<Model> models = new List<Model> ();
            models.Add(dataModel);
            models.Add(reporterModel);

            foreach (Model model_a in models)
            {
                Dictionary<string, EventHandler<EventArgs>> pub = model_a.pub;
                foreach (Model model_b in models)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, Delegate> sub = model_b.sub;
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, EventHandler<EventArgs>> entry in pub)
                    {
                        if (sub.ContainsKey(entry.Key))
                        {
                            pub[entry.Key] += reporterModel.onData;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Test Event system
            dataModel.onData(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Area all events of the form `EventHandler<EventArgs>`? Or might there be different event signatures?

Comment: Eventually they will contain a range of derivatives of EventArgs; all will be of the EventHandler form.

Comment: Maybe [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) could be of help here?